# Setting HTML Button`onclick` in template literal

Tags: javascript, html, template-literals, html5-template

I have an html template that i'm using template literals for. The function looks like the below

```
// postCreator.js
export const blogPostMaker = ({ title, content, address, id }, deletePost) => {
  const innerHtml = `
  <blog-post>
    <h1 class='title'>${title}</h1>
    <p class='content'>${content}</p>
    <p class='address'>${address}</p>
    <button onclick='${() => deletePost(id)}'>Delete</button>
  </blog-post>
  `
  return innerHtml
}


//Blog.js
  postHelper.getSeriesOfPosts(10)
  .then(resp => {
    resp.forEach(post => (blogDiv.innerHTML += blogPostMaker(post, postHelper.deletePost)))
  })
```

What I can't figure out is how to get the onclick to work. I've tried passing in an anon function in `Blog.js` to the `postCreator` as well with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `<button onclick="postHelper.deletePost(${id})">Delete</button>` ?

Comment: That would work if I exposed the `postHelper` object globally, but I don't think I want to do that.  I don't think what I'm trying to do is possible unless I expose globals based on my reading of how HTML handles inline JS.

Answer (score 6):

[Miroslav Savovski's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46264155/4826740) solution works but they did not explain why, so I thought I would add this answer with the reasoning behind that and a step-by-step of how it is actually working, and why the OP's solution was not working initially.

**TLDR?** Scroll to the last two code snippets.

With template literals when you put a function inside of them it executes that function, so let's say we have a simple function like this that just returns a string of `'blue'`:

```
const getBlueColor = () => 'blue'
```

And then we call this function inside of a template literal like this:

```
`The color is ${getBlueColor()}`
```

What happens is that the `getBlueColor()` is called right when that code is executed.

Now lets say we wanted to do this `onclick` instead like this:

```
<button onclick="${getBlueColor()}"></button>
```

What is happening is that `getBlueColor` is not being executed `onclick`, it's actually executed when the template literal is executed.

The way we fix this is to prevent the template literal from executing this function by simply removing the template literal:

```
<button onclick="getBlueColor()"></button>
```

But now let's say you want to pass in some parameters to a function like `getOppositeColor(color)` like this:

```
<button onclick="getOppositeColor(color)"></button>
```

This will not work because `color` won't be defined. So you need to wrap *that* with a template literal and in a string like this:

```
<button onclick="getOppositeColor('${color}')"><button>
```

Now with this you will be calling the `onclick` when the user clicks the button, and you will be passing it a string of the `color` like this:

```
getOppositeColor('blue')
```

Comment: the object is converting into `[object Object]` when wrapping in single quotes

Comment: this worked: `onclick='doSomething(${JSON.stringify(obj)})'`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to expose the event callback globally, you should attach it in the JS part of the code with `addEventListener()` :

```
// postCreator.js
export const blogPostMaker = ({ title, content, address, id }) => 
  `
  <blog-post id='${id}'>
    <h1 class='title'>${title}</h1>
    <p class='content'>${content}</p>
    <p class='address'>${address}</p>
    <button>Delete</button>
  </blog-post>
  `

//Blog.js
  postHelper.getSeriesOfPosts(10).then(resp => {
    resp.forEach(post => {
      blogDiv.innerHTML += blogPostMaker(post)
      blogDiv.querySelector(`blog-post[id="${post.id}"] > button`)
        .addEventListener('click', () => postHelper.deletePost(post.id))
  })
```

*Note:* it's not the most efficient way to do it but it keeps your file structure.

Instead I would create the `<button>` directly with `createElement()` and then add it to DOM with `appendChild()`, or I would use a DocumentFragment or a `<template>` in order to avoid `querySelector()` on all of the `blogDiv`.

---

If you absolutely want to use inline JS without exposing the helper you'll need to define your  as a component (for example a Custom Element).

Answer (score 5):

```js
const markUp = `
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
`;

document.body.innerHTML = markUp;

window.myFunction = () => {
    console.log('Button clicked');
};
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain a bit about your code.